# Is there a way to send multiples documents to MongoDB over time using a loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, stream, real-time

I'm struggling on sending sensors-data to mongodb using javascript .
I found some solutions like mongodb Atlas etc .. ,but I am looking for a simple manner to do it ,Here is my code

```
const db =client.db(databaseName)

function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
while(true) {

    const data = async (timestep, temperature) => {

        const post = await db.collection('temperature').insertOne({
            timestep: timestep,
            data: temperature
        })
        await timeout(3000);
        return post


    }
    data("2020", 23).then((result) => console.log(result))

}
```

And I get some errors :

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[3454:0x10417e000]    28749 ms: Mark-sweep 2028.1 (2066.2) -> 2027.4 (2065.2) MB, 2078.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.102, current mu = 0.006) allocation failure GC in old space requested
[3454:0x10417e000]    30843 ms: Mark-sweep 2028.4 (2065.2) -> 2028.0 (2065.7) MB, 2081.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.055, current mu = 0.006) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution ,using Cron Job  .
you can install it  via
`npm i cron`